# Connecting a phone to my PC disables the WiFi adapter on the computer

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, usb

This problem has persisted for months now; I'm in desperate need of a solution.

When I connect multiple different smartphones to my PC by USB, the WiFi adapter (mounted on my wall, connected via USB to my PC) freezes and eventually disconnects from the PC (as if I manually unplugged it from the USB port).  The WiFi icon disappears, and as my PC is not cabled to our router, the no network symbol shows up instead.

Computer information: (complete system specifications, as requested)

- **64-bit Windows 7 Professional Edition** running on an **Intel Xeon E5450** in [Gigabyte G41-MTS2P](http://download1.gigabyte.us/Files/Manual/mb_manual_ga-g41mt-d3p(s2p)_v1.3_e.pdf) motherboard with **6GB** of **DDR3 1333MHz RAM** (2+4 configuration, running in Intel Flex mode)
- Graphics card is an **ASUS Phoenix GT 1030**, and I have a generic **1TB Toshiba HDD**
  Miscellaneous devices are:
- **Generic Front USB panel** (+2 USB 2.0 ports and front audio) connected over the
  motherboards's F_AUDIO and the 1st USB2.0 headers
- **Optical drive** connected over SATA 2
- **Flash card front face panel**, connected over the
  2nd USB2.0 header
- **TP-Link TL-WN722N** WiFi adapter connected over a USB 2.0 on the back
- **Generic USB keyboard and mouse**, and a **Logitech Wingman** controller connected over a USB 2.0 on the back respectively
- **Benq GW2270H** connected over HDMI to my GT 1030
- My laptop (used as a game server with friends) connected over ethernet to my PC

Tested phones: (BOTH provide the same result)

- Huawei P9 Lite 2017
- Microsoft Lumia 640  (which has no USB tethering capability)

Attempted fixes so far:

- Reinstall wireless drivers
- Reinstall device-related drivers for both

Comment: @K7AAY full specifications added & as far as I remember, Huawei phones disable it once they get disconnected (can't check as it's in repair right now), and my Lumia does not support USB tethering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [UsbDevView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html) I have removed every single possible USB driver from my computer (then reinstalling the ones I needed) seems to have fixed the issue.
Technology is weird.

Answer (score 0):

I see two hardware solutions, since all your USB ports are run off one controller (ref. [pg. 7](http://download1.gigabyte.us/Files/Manual/mb_manual_ga-g41mt-d3p(s2p)_v1.3_e.pdf)) in your [Southbridge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbridge_(computing)) chip.

A) Add a [$25 USB3 PCIe card](https://www.google.com/search?q=USB3%20PCIe%20x1%20card) in one of your two PCIe x1 (preferred over PCI, [twice as fast](https://naplestech.com/bus-speeds/)) for your phones. Give the phone port its own controller and it won't bark at the WiFi and hang things up. Most cards have multiple USB3 internal and external, so if your case cabling permits, you might be able to bring USB3 to your front case ports.

B) Add a [PCIe x1 WiFi card](https://www.google.com/search?q=WiFi%20802.11n%20PCIe%20x1) instead of a USB card and recycle the wall wart. Less cables more better. That's an 802.11n 2.4/5GHz WiFi card; make sure what you get matches or exceeds what your laptop (and guests' laptops) will do.

Comment: Possible answer, will be ordering a USB 3.0 add-in card tomorrow on the way home from school (and possibly a switch as well, so I can finally get ethernet into my room)